# maven-jaxb2-plugin don't generate files if already equal one exist

Tags: maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using `maven-jaxb2-plugin` to generate files from a `dld` file provided by 3-rd party.

How to prevent regeneration of the same files each time, even without changes been made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

The root cause for it was the disclaimer generated in files beginning which added the **randomndess** factor into the files.

```
This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.2-hudson-jaxb-ri-2.2-63- 
See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
Generated on: XXX XXX XXX
```

Adding `<args><arg>-no-header</arg></args>` in plugin's `pom` configuration solved the issue.

Comment: You can also use `<noFileHeader>true</noFileHeader>` configuration element of the plugin.

Comment: Even prettier. Thanks!